# How can I create this layout that spans multiple rows using Android LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

What can I do to just bring up these ImageButtons in this layout with the LinearLayout? I've already tried it with the TableLayout, but it doesn't worked for me because not all rows with ImageButtons as its children were displayed.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6PkZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by nesting layouts inside layouts. Hint;

```
<LinearLayout
 android: orientation = "vertical">
     <LinearLayout
      android: orientation = "horizontal">•
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
     </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout
      android: orientation = "horizontal">
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
          <Button.../>
     </LinearLayout>
     <RelativeLayout>
          <LinearLayout
           android: orientation = "horizontal"
           android: id = @+id/"abc">
              <Button.../>
              <Button.../>
              <Button.../>
          </LinearLayout>
          <LinearLayout
           android: orientation = "horizontal">•
              <Button.../>
              <Button.../>
              <Button.../>
          </LinearLayout>
              <Button...
               android: layout_toRightOf=" @id/abc"/>
     </RelativeLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

You can also nest layouts in ConstraintLayout. It all depends on the way you want to achieve the result

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! But with the RelativeLayout and the 2 LinearLayouts as it's children it won't work, because you can't use layout_weight with the 2 LinearLayouts. This means that you can't tell them that they should take the same space.

Comment: You are correct, but there is another way to do this. The simplest is to change the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and assign layout weight,

Comment: Yes, this is that what I did in my answer below. And it works great! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of fiddling, I have now managed to design the above layout. Of course, what's striking is that there are a lot of nested linear layouts, but at least I managed it.
Maybe someone else has an idea to avoid these nested linear layouts and if not, then I leave it that way, because it fulfills its purpose anyway.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/ >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```